# Modifying an index in an array, using pointers

Tags: arrays

I'm attempting to modify an array using only pointers.

```
void modify(){
int *ptr = &b[2];
*ptr = 90;
}

//I have my main function  
void main() {
  int b[15];
//fill the array with values using loop..skipping this part 
 modify();
}
```

The error that its giving me is : error: use of undeclared identifier 'b'

Can anyone give me some insight as to why the compiler does not recognize the array b?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`b` is declared as a local variable in `main()`, and thus can only be accessed  by `main()`. To make `b` visible to other functions, make it a global variable by declaring it outside of any functions:

```
int b[3];

void modify(){
    int *ptr = &b[2];
    *ptr = 90;
}

int main(void) { //This is one of the standard signatures of main
    //Fill the array with values using a loop
    modify();
    return 0; //main returns an int
}
```